# keyboard shortcut does not open Form 3 as intended

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-c#-express-2010

I need form to add the keys alt+1 to open form 3 but for some reason when I debug and press the shortcut it does not open the shortcut

Here is the code segment from form 2

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.ShowDialog();
    }

}
```

As i said it dose not open form 3 as intended if ti helps here is the whole code i am working with in form 2:
[Updated] [unsolved]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myForm = new Form2();
            myForm.Show();

        }
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                Form3 f3 = new Form3();
                f3.ShowDialog();
            }

        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the KeyPreview=True for Form2?

Comment: It should work with preview.. Your code looks a bit confusing why does Form2 have a Form1_KeyDown event? Is this Form1 or Form2? Also Form2 which is created from pictureBox_Click will disappear when it is garbage collected. You need to store a member variable outside the method to hold the reference to the form if you call Form.Show instead of Form.ShowDialog(). ShowDialog blocks.. and waits for close to be called, Form.Show does not.. therefore your method will end and the Form2 will be available for collection (then Dispose will be called and the form will be destroyed)

Comment: your `Form1_KeyDown...` in your class `Form2` is a remarkable point, you want to register the `KeyDown` event handler with name `Form1_KeyDown` for your `Form2`? I guess you even haven't any subscription for your `Form2.KeyDown` event.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the form's [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property set to True.